# PHP Code to Display Term URL & Name of a Post Under a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, terms

I am featuring a post in my footer(outside the loop) from a custom post type and am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin to do so. This is the code I am using:

```
<h5>Featured Movie</h5>
<?php query_posts(array(
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'post_type' => 'movies',
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'meta_key' => 'featured_movie',
'meta_compare' => '=',
'meta_value' => 1,
'paged' => $paged
)
); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="popcontainer">
<div class="popthumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full-thumbnail');?></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
"<?php the_content(); ?>"
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

While that does exactly what I need it to, I also need some code in there that displays & links to the term(s) that are associated with whatever post being featured at the moment.  However the code I have asks me to specify a taxonomy and I dont think that's the way to go as it's too limiting & I want to be able to pull from every post in the `movies` custom post type regardless of what taxonomies and terms they have. The code I have right now is

```
<?php   // Get terms for post
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'genre' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
$term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'genre' );
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 unset($term);
} } ?>
```

As you can see I had to specify `genre` as the taxonomy for the sake of having it show up on my site & for the sake of this example but I dont want to specify a taxonomy bc doing so leaves out every other taxonomy I have like `ratings` or `release date`. Sure I could put every single one of my taxonomies into the code to make sure they're all included but there has to be an easier way. Further, how do I make sure that every term associated with the post is displayed.

Comment: This is a much, much better formulated question than the other one :)

Comment: This is a totally different issue and question though lol. I will repost the other when I figure out how to ask it. Seems I needed to already have some form of code in rotation for you to get the gist of what I was saying but since I don't I'm afraid when I repost it is gonna sound a lot like it did at first...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_object_taxonomies`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies) to get all of the taxonomies registered to a particular post type.

Also, [don't use `query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) for secondary queries. or ever, actually. Use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'movies',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'meta_key' => 'featured_movie',
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'meta_value' => 1,
);
$movie = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $movie->have_posts() ){
    while( $movie->have_posts() ){
        $movie->the_post();

        // your post template tags
        the_title();
        the_post_thumbnail('full-thumbnail');

        // taxonomies/terms
        if( $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( 'movies' ) ){
            foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ){
                if( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , $taxonomy ) ){
                    foreach( $terms as $term ){
                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Hello Milo! I tried your code and while it does show me every term associated with the post I am still getting an error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/site-path-goes-here/footer.php on line 31` My actual post isn't showing but the terms associated with it are.

Comment: yeah sorry, I was just showing a quick example - the two `foreach`s should be wrapped in `if( $taxonomies )` and `if( $terms )` so you don't try to iterate over an empty set of data (like in your original example). You don't see any post data because there aren't any template tags in my example outputting it. add `the_title()` or `the_content()` in there to see your post title/content.

Comment: Ok maybe I shouldve said I'm just above being a novice lol! I would totally appreciate you breaking it down so I wont mess anything up. I did try to paste in `the_content()` snippets from my original example up top after I realized they weren't in there but it didnt work & I am further frustrating myself lol.. am also not sure what you mean by putting `if` on the two `foreach` lines. I see it I just don't understand.

Comment: I just pasted `if( $taxonomies ) ` directly before `foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ){` to get `if( $taxonomies ) foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ){` and then pasted `if( $terms )` directly before `foreach( $terms as $term ){` to get `if( $terms ) foreach( $terms as $term ){` in your code and got no errors. Is this correct though?